# Rails default_url_options for actioncontroller to auto format all urls/paths with .html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, friendly-url, actioncontroller

One of our requirements was that all our url's ended with .html
We've overridden the default_url_options method to add the format to the options

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  options.merge(:format => 'html')
end
```

This works great in the most part...
but it causes issue with the following routes:

```
map.home '/', :controller => 'home'
map.root :controller => 'home'
```

it causes these routes to return:

```
domain.com/?format=html
```

I need to find a way to make an exception to these routes, is this possible or does anyone know a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this make it work with haml... (erb untested)

```
map.home '/', :controller => 'home', :format => 'html'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me in a quick test.

```
map.home '/', :controller => 'home', :format => ''
```

Comment: Implementing this on rails 2.3.2 gives me....

Processing ApplicationController#index to  (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-08-17 09:50:45) [GET]
  Parameters: {"format"=>"", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"home"}

ArgumentError (interning empty string):
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-edge-2.1.12/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:14:in `render'

Comment: yeah, I didn't try it with haml - sorry.

Comment: no worries, it must be something to do with the way haml hooks into render